# What grammatical structure is this parenthetical?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> An equivalent formulation, **generalizable to interacting systems**, is to consider...

I want to know what kind of grammatical structure the part "generalizable to interacting systems" is. It is not a participle construction, right? What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Generalizable* is an adjective, and the phrase *generalizable to interacting systems* post-modifies *formulation*. It could also be expressed as ***which is*** generalizable to interacting systems.

Comment: It should also be noted that adjectives derived from verbs with _-able_ do act somewhat like participles in that they tend to retain the original verb’s complements. ‘Generalise’, for example, is used with a complement _to + NP_, and ‘generalisable’ keeps this possibility. They can also take agentive complements (_by + NP_ to indicate the agent of the possible action).

Comment: @Barrie England  Thank you Barrie England! I have another question.Can the two commas be omitted? Written as "An equivalent formulation generalizable to interacting systems is to consider..." and "An equivalent formulation which is generalizable to interacting systems is to consider...

Comment: If _(which is) generalizable to interacting systems_ is an essential part of the sentence, if, in other words, it defines which formulation is under consideration, then the convention is to omit the commas. You would include them, on the other hand, if you regarded ‘generalizable to interacting systems’ as no more than additional information.